# Данные из файла в вектор, массив типа point

Tags: c++

Всем доброго вечера, возник вопрос. Имеется файл, пусть будет обычный текстовый `.txt`, из него необходимо данные считать в вектор `vector<point> MyVector;`
Каким образом считывать данные из файла, если они в таком виде:

```
0 0 
0 10
10 10
10 0
```

Единственное, пробовал вот так, с промежуточной переменной.

```
MyVector.push_back(in);
```

Необходимо каждый элемент считать на свое место `MyVector[i].x; MyVector[i].y` Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Ну читайте парами - `in >> MyVector[i].x >> MyVector[i].y` или через те же дополнительные переменные...

Answer (score -1):

На сколько я понимаю, то `point` - это клас или структура.
Нужно  создать конструктор класса

```
 public point(int x, int y){
     this->x = x;
     this->y = y;
 }
```

А потом создавать екземпляр

```
my_list.push_back(new point (elements [0], elements[1]));
```